# How to kill a JUnit test run in Eclipse that has entered an infinte loop

Tags: eclipse, junit, infinite-loop

I have some Java code that I am unit testing using JUnit, running inside Eclipse (Neon). It so happens that some code under test has a bug in it, causing it to enter an infinite loop. The JUnit run then, of course, does not finish. How do I kill the test run?

The button for stopping the test run ("Stop JUnit Test Run") does not work well: the GUI seems to think that it has stopped the test run, but a look at the CPU activity (using `top`, for example), shows that a Java thread is still running. I can kill the thread myself by sending it a kill signal. But that seems a kludge and is inconvenient. Is there a better way, available within Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kill it from the console view, using the red button. This stops the process.

[image]

Stopping it from the junit view only asks it to stop.

Answer (score 5):

You can handle such things with JUnit by specifying a time-out within
the `@Test` annotation. For example:

```
// Simple test-case which will always fail with time-out
@Test(timeout = 1000 * 60) throws Exception // 60 seconds 
public void testSomething() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {  // 100 seconds
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If your test method doesn't finish on time,
then JUnit will interrupt it and report a test failure.
For the example above it will be:

```
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 60000 milliseconds
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at my.package.Test1.testSomething(Test1.java:12)
```

Comment: Useful if you anticipate a failure of a particular test *might* cause an infinite loop. Not so useful if you have no good reason to suspect that, or a subsequent attempted re-factoring introduces an infinite loop.

Comment: @Raedwald Well, I would turn around your reasoning and annotate *every* test method with `@Test(timeout=60000)` (or some other arbitrarily high timeout) even if I do *not* have any reason to expect an infinite loop.

Comment: Adding that to *every* test is a code smell, I think.

Comment: @Raedwald Yes indeed, it looks smelly. A better way would be to set a default time-out as described in this [answer to "Set JUnit timeout in eclipse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097821/set-junit-timeout-in-eclipse/13600361#13600361).

Answer (score 0):

First, try Matthew Farwell's answer. If that doesn't work then you have to go to your processes running (ctrl+shift+esc on windows, then processes tab) and select the `java.exe` task, then end process. In the event you ever need to kill eclipse, it's `javaw.exe`